# Creating nested Map with different type

Tags: scala

I am try to create map with different map inside

```
val mymap = Map("name"->"somename",Map(1->2))
```

I got from compiler:

```
scala: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]
 required: (?, ?)
  val mymap = Map("name"->"somename",Map(1->2))
                                        ^
```

Comment: Presumably you need some key for your nested `Map` which is the value...

Answer (score 4):

Why do you expect it to work? You've provided only key without value:

```
val key = Map(1->2)
val mymap = Map("name"->"somename", key)
```

Perhaps you wanted to combine two maps? This can be done with:

```
val mymap = Map("name"->"somename") ++ Map(1->2)
// scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Any] = Map(name -> somename, 1 -> 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

A Map consists of key-value pairs (whose type is `(?, ?)`). You have to assign the Map value to a key as well:

```
val mymap = Map("name"->"somename","othername"->Map(1->2))
```